# Sklearn SelectFromModel with L1 regularized Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

As part of my pipeline I wanted to use `LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')` for feature selection in combination with `SelectFromModel`. In order to choose the right amount of regularization, I optimized the regularization parameter `C` with `GridSearchCV`.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LassoCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RepeatedStratifiedKFold
import numpy as np

seed = 111
breast = load_breast_cancer()
X = breast.data
y = breast.target
LR_L1 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', random_state=seed, solver='saga', max_iter=1e5)
pipeline = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()),
                     ('SelectFromModel', SelectFromModel(LR_L1)),
                     ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=seed))])
Lambda = np.array([])
for i in [1e-1, 1, 1e-2, 1e-3]:
    Lambda = np.append(Lambda, i * np.arange(2, 11, 2))
param_grid = {'SelectFromModel__estimator__C': Lambda,
              'classifier_max_features': np.arange(10,100, 10)}
clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=7, cv=RepeatedStratifiedKFold(random_state=seed),
                   verbose=1)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

For some values of `C` I got the following warning :

```
UserWarning: No features were selected: either the data is too noisy or the selection test too strict.
```

which is understandable. 
However, when fitting the same `LogisticRegression` as a classifier instead as feature selection, here I got no problem while the training sets and the hyperparameters used to fit the algorithm are the same. Looking at the results, there is no possibility that there is 0 features with coefficients different from 0.

```
pipeline2 = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()),
                     ('classifier', LR_L1)])
param_grid2 = {'classifier__C': Lambda}
clf2 = GridSearchCV(pipeline2, param_grid2, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=7, cv=RepeatedStratifiedKFold(random_state=seed),
                    verbose=1)
clf2.fit(X, y)
```

Is this a bug or is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, but would this be useful to you? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html

Comment: I just provide a simple example of my problem here. 
I use Nested cross validation to get my model performance with inner loop to optimize the hyperparameters. 
I would like to optimize the regularization at the same level, i.e. in the inner loop, than the other parameters (e.g. `max_features` for my RF here in the example) and not to have another level of cross validation in which there will be less sample.

Comment: Please do not edit the question *after* an answer has been provided in a way that renders the answer invalid (rolled back in its previous version).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Looking at the results, there is no possibility that there is 0 features with coefficients different from 0"?  The `cv_results_`?

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes that was what I was looking at, but I shouldn't. See my comments on the answer below

Comment: Reviving a dead thread in case anyone else stumbles on this later: it looks like you're using lambda to be the strength of penalty, but the sklearn documentation notes that C is inversely related to penalization. Larger C = less penalty. So you may want to take 1/lambda to solve this issue. Also, the grid of lambdas for beyond which all coefficients will be zero can be found in closed form, in section 2.5 of this paper: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/paper

Answer (score 2):

You caught an error because of too strong regularization for the LogisticRegression. There is also a typo in `param_grid` for the parameter `classifier_max_features` - it should be `classifier__max_features` (two underscores).

With the regularization value `C >= 1e-2` the code works. Here you can find a [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GaEgMMU25981Fs1EbEXzZ-m6Db5Hgizt?usp=sharing) with your example.

One more note - the dataset is too small for such a complex manipulation.

Comment: In facts the problem append for very small values of C (2e-3 and 4e-3 if I am correct) but you restricted your hyperparameters grid to bigger values. Again, it is just an example to reproduce the problem I have, the parameters tested are not optimal.
Anyway, I have the feeling that it shouldn't behave as it does, i.e. return 0 non-zero coefficients in `SelectFromModel` but succeed to fit when outside of this object

Comment: After a bit more investigations, I found that coefficients are the same in both cases. I got baited by the results of Logistic Regression when all coefficients are 0. It is equal to 0.5, I don't why I was expected something like NaN. Thus, there is nothing else than a too strong regularization as you suggested.